# how can i save and return to same record on django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to create a new order and when i save it i would like that it return me to a page with the same order id, not index as following.

```
def order_create(request):
    print(request.POST)
    order_number = request.GET['order_number']
    date = request.GET['date']
    client = request.GET['client']
    order_details = order(order_number=order_number, date=date, client=client)
    order_details.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Why do you redirect back to the root page if you know thats not what you want to do?

Comment: i redirect it to the root to get all records then i choose the record. so now i want to save to redirect to same record

Answer (score 0):

instead of `return redirect('/')`

use something like:

```
return redirect(reverse("orders:view", kwargs={"order_id": order_number}))
```

This depends on if your urls entry is similar to:

```
path("orders/<int:order_id>/", view=view.view_order, name="view")
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it gives me : name 'reverse' is not defined. and why you put this "orders:detail" ? is it related to what ?

Comment: `from django.urls import reverse`, and I should have typed "orders:view" which is just an example of what your urls entry _might_ look like. "orders" is the app, "view" is the name.